# MySQL error 1054: Unknown column in having clause

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1054

Query:

```
  SELECT SUM(ProductCost) 
    FROM `tblBasket` 
GROUP BY ProductCode
  HAVING BasketSessionID = '3429782d79c68834ea698bb4116eef5e'
```

Showing Error Like:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'BasketSessionID' in 'having clause'

What is the mistake in my query?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a where clause in place of the having clause:

```
SELECT SUM(ProductCost) 
FROM `tblBasket` 
WHERE BasketSessionID ='3429782d79c68834ea698bb4116eef5e'
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Comment: FYI - you would use the HAVING clause if you only wanted products where the SUM of the cost is greater than (or some other comparison):  SELECT productID, Sum(ProductCost) FROM tblBasket GROUP BY productID HAVING SUM(ProductCost) > 10 will show all the products where the cost is greater than 10.  You can't do that in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use a where clause not having.

Answer (score 2):

HAVING filters out aggregates. You should try GROUP BY.